# How to fetch all changes of values from _AUD table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

We are using hibernate-envers 3.6.3.final and the `*._AUD` tables are created successfully. I need to generate a report (a table) based log information to shows to the user, a list of changes of an object. Something likes the following

```
Id | modified_by  | old_value | new_value | timestamp
1  | user1        | Boby77    | Boby      | 2015-02-04 23:18:17
2  | user2        | Boby      | Bob       | 2015-02-06 20:20:10
```

I am unable to fetch all the data from `*._AUD` table. How do I fetch all changes of values from the audit table? How do I do this?

I am using the following code but it returns the default revisions:

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = AuditReaderFactory
                .get(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(Myentity.class, false, true);

List<Object[]> list = auditQuery.getResultList();
```

The above query returns the following:

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: bla.bla.Myclass@71587682
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 1, revisionDate = 12 May, 2015 4:25:16 AM)
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: MOD
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: bla.bla.Myclass@66cc8af0
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 2, revisionDate = 12 May, 2015 4:31:02 AM)
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: DEL
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: bla.bla.Myclass@7eb5c749
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 3, revisionDate = 12 May, 2015 4:31:02 AM)
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: ADD
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: bla.bla.Myclass@502eca9c
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 4, revisionDate = 12 May, 2015 5:08:52 AM)
>       XXXXXXXXXXXXXX :: MOD

But I don't want this. I need the all changes of what I did liks the above table. How do I do this?

Comment: You can always use any customized JPQL, Criteria or native query on your audit table. Make sure you use entity manager instead of AuditReader.